# what are curry and uncurry in high-order functions in ML

Tags: sml, higher-order-functions, currying, ml

```
fun curry f x y = f (x, y); 
fun uncurry f (x, y) = f x y; 
fun compose (f, g) x = f (g x);
```

I understand compose function, but not quite understand curry and uncurry in ML. Can anyone explain these?

Also, what do the following two lines mean?

```
(1) compose (compose, uncurry compose)
(2) compose (uncurry compose, compose)
```

Answer (score 13):

If you look at the types, then you will clearly see what `curry` and `uncurry` does.

Remember that it is possible to define function which either takes its arguments as one big tuple, or as multiple arguments (in reality it becomes a "chain" of functions each taking 1 argument, see this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)):

```
fun foo (a,x) = a*x+10
fun bar a x = a*x+20
```

The difference is clearly seen in their types:

```
val foo = fn : int * int -> int
val bar = fn : int -> int -> int
```

The `curry` function "transforms" a function that takes its arguments as a tuple, into a "chain" of functions that each takes 1 of the arguments. This is specifically handy when we want to compose a series of functions where some of them have been partially applied with arguments. See how the type of `foo` is changed:

```
- curry foo;
val it = fn : int -> int -> int
```

Now we can try and compose the two functions:

```
- (curry foo 5 o bar 1) 4;
val it = 130 : int
```

First 4 is applied to `bar 1` as the argument `x`, then the result of that computation (`bar 1 4`) is given as the `x` argument to `foo`.

Obviously `uncurry` is used for the reverse process:

```
- uncurry bar;
val it = fn : int * int -> int
```