# Function data type is unclear in SML

Tags: sml

Given the following function in SML:

```
fun i a b = let fun j()=a+1 in j end;
```

The data type of the function is:

```
val i = fn : int -> 'a -> unit -> int
```

I don't understand why `int -> 'a -> unit -> int`?

And why not `(int * a') -> unit -> int`, since the function `i` receives two inputs.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550740/sml-why-functions-always-take-one-argument-make-language-flexible/14554122#14554122), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432696/what-does-this-function-signature-mean-in-sml/14438864#14438864) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395564/what-are-curry-and-uncurry-in-high-order-functions-in-ml/8400194#8400194) will enlighten you a bit more on currying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you defined the function as `fun i (a,b) = ...` then it would take a tuple as an argument and its type would indeed be `(int * 'a) -> unit -> int`. It would be called as `i (23,42) ()` (`(23,42)` being a tuple and `()` being the unit value).

However you defined it as `fun i a b = ...`, which defines a function that takes an argument and then returns another function that takes the next argument. It is a shortcut for `fun i a = fn b => ...`. It can be called as `i a b ()`.

Answer (score 2):

This function (as well, as any function in SML) is actually receive *one* input, because of currying.

Technically there is function that takes unit, that returns function that takes 'a that returns function that takes int.

So

```
fun foo a b = a + b;
```

is [just an syntactic sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432696/what-does-this-function-signature-mean-in-sml/14438864#14438864) to

```
fun foo a = fn b => a + b;
```

and so on.

Comment: Currying, not carrying. ;)

Comment: @AndreasRossberg I hope mr. Haskell will forgive me ;-)